# How to hide line graph with its legend in coreplot?

Tags: ios, xcode, graph, core-plot

I have two graphs. I want to hide one graph on click. I know how to hide graph but when i hide it the legend is still visible. How to hide it?

To hide the graph i use the following line of code:
`_graphPlot.bancaOneLinePlot.hidden=YES;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove plot from legend:

```
[_graph.legend removePlot:_bancaOneLinePlot];
```

To add again:

```
 [_graph.legend addPlot:_bancaOneLinePlot];
```

[Reference](https://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg-history/efa73ee50d8edfd0e1d4294cf4bd2c07d9f8af77/documentation/html/iOS/interface_c_p_t_legend.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily hide the plot when you tap the legend item.
Please see my answer below.  Probably this code will be usefull for you.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13950514/1220922