# Hide plot with touch event - Core Plot

Tags: events, plot, touch, hide, core-plot

I whould like to make a graph in Core Plot and I need to have a "switch" to each (Scatter)plot.

The objective is, when the user tap the "switch", the associated plot hide/show. For example, I have a graph with 5 Scatterplot's and a "switch" to each plot. When I tap the "switch
1" the "plot1" is hidden or show.

I've already read this tutorial but it does not what I want: [Touch Event on LEGENDS in Coreplot iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525803/touch-event-on-legends-in-coreplot-ios)

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by a "switch"? A separate control such as a button, or some part of the graph?

Comment: It could be throught a legend, for example, I have a legend to each plot, and when you click on one legend, it "turns off/on" the legend and hides/show the associated plot. I have an image ilustrating the objective [link](https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=554&can=4)

Comment: I'm working on adding a legend delegate method that will notify the delegate when the user touches a legend entry. Watch the status on the Core Plot issue tracker ([issue #444](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=444)) to see when the update is finished.